# MotionLayout in AndroidX does not exist

Tags: android, sdk, android-motionlayout

Android Studio cannot find MotionLayout in xml. I use the `androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout` tag and get a gray screen. I’m also implementing `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4'` and changing to alpha02 changes nothing. I already found a question with the same problem, but it also had no solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used the wrong implentation in gradle. Correct is `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'`

Answer (score 0):

after i updated everything is needed ,my problem resolved with clean project in build!